# Radio button stays checked after clicking another one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set up a series of radio buttons which will become unchecked after clicking another one, i.e. only one can be checked at a time. I also make a text area below the radio buttons appear or disappear based on which radio button has been selected. My html is

```
<table id="tableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="selectTitle">
          Some Select
        </div>
        <select id="stuff">
          <option value="0">option 0</option>
          <option value="1">option 1</option>
          <option value="2">option 2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>
          Radio Options
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input id="rad1" type="radio" /> rad1 </li>
          <li>
            <input id="rad2" type="radio" /> rad2 </li>
          <li>
            <input id="rad2" type="radio" /> rad3 </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input id="textArea" type="textarea" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and my javascript is

```
$("#rad1").click(function() {
  $("#rad2").prop("checked", false);
  $("#rad3").prop("checked", false);
  $("#textArea").hide();
});
$("#rad2").click(function() {
  $("#rad1").prop("checked", false);
  $("#rad3").prop("checked", false);
  $("#textArea").hide();
});
$("#rad3").click(function() {
  $("#rad1").prop("checked", false);
  $("#rad2").prop("checked", false);
  $("#textArea").show();
});
```

Here's the problem:

rad1 and rad2 work correctly. When you click on them, the buttons toggle from being checked to unchecked as expected. However, when you click rad3, it stays checked, and won't become unchecked until you refresh the page. I looked through the cases, and nothing seems to be different between them. Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divdiff1/edczzpap/) with my code. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you want to group radio buttons they all need to have the exact same `name` attribute.

Comment: You've also a duplicate `id` for `rad2`

Comment: Missed that id. It looks like that, combined with adding the name attribute resolved the issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you give your radio inputs same name, they would work as you uexpect:

```
<ul>
    <li><input id="rad1" name="rad" type="radio" /> rad1 </li>
    <li><input id="rad2" name="rad" type="radio" /> rad2 </li>
    <li><input id="rad3" name="rad" type="radio" /> rad3 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver

Answer (score 6):

If you want to group radio buttons they all need to have the exact same `name` attribute. Then you get the behaviour by default. From there you can apply a single `change` event handler to toggle the `#textarea` element based on the selected value.

Also note that you duplicated the `rad2` id, which is invalid, and also radio inputs require a `value` attribute. Try this:

```js
$('input[name="foo"]').change(function() {
    $('#textArea').toggle(this.value == '3');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><input id="rad1" type="radio" value="1" name="foo" />rad1</li>
  <li><input id="rad2" type="radio" value="2" name="foo" />rad2</li>
  <li><input id="rad3" type="radio" value="3" name="foo" checked="true" />rad3</li>
</ul>

<input id="textArea" type="textarea" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put the`name` property to all your radios in a group.
The `name` should be the same in your 3 radios.
like:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Val 1">
<input type="radio" name="radio" value="Val 2">
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 26 in your HTML has an issue, you have duplicated the ID for type rad3.

Changed the id to rad3 and seems to be working as expected.